# Finding out in which MMT source file a constant/theory/... was declared

Tags: development-environment, mmt

Say I remember a constant or theory name, but totally forgot where it is declared. Perhaps, I don't even know in which MMT archive it is declared. How can I find out the source file?

Can I just open an MMT shell, load all archives I have on my disk, and issue some command `find_constant <constant name>`? Does such a command exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you know about the thing whose declaration point you seek:

- **If you don't know anything, i.e. if you don't even have a typechecking file where the thing is used.**

  Then the easiest way to find out the point of declaration is to just grep over all `*.mmt` files with regexes. For (typed) constants, use `<constant name>\s*?:`. It will match constant declarations, followed by some optional whitespace, and a colon.

  With Notepad++, this is easy to do. Say, you wanted to know where `congT` is declared. Then you would do:

  [image]
- **You have a typechecking MMT file where the thing you are looking for is used.**

  Then use the [MMT IntelliJ plugin](https://uniformal.github.io/doc/applications/intellij/) and its document tree: first typecheck the file at hand, and then look in the sidekick for the occurrence of the constant:

  [image]

  Activating the *Navigate* option is particularly helpful here: with that you can simply click with your mouse on the thing whose point of declaration you seek (here e.g. `nat_lit`) and immediately have it revealed in the sidekick. Here, the sidekick shows `nat_lit (?NatLiterals)` meaning that the constant was defined in the theory `NatLiterals`. Ideally, you know where that theory is declared.

  In theory, you could also control-click on the constant, but that doesn't currently work for reasons beyond my knowledge.